# Ordering Target number sets for similarity with Source number set

Tags: algorithm, indexing

I have 1 Source number set (or vector) with 50 integer numbers between 1 and 100
(= a profile with 50 characteristics rated between 1 and 100)

I have 1,000,000 Target number sets (or vectors), also each with 50 integer numbers
(= 1M more of such profiles)

I want to order the 1,000,000 Target sets by similarity to the Source set
(= I want to browse through best to worst match)

I want the routine to return an ordered list in <1 sec (triggered from web application, returned to laptop and/or mobile device)
(= Performance requirement for end user)

I want the routine to do this even when there are 100 similar requests being submitted at the same time for different Source number sets
(= Support for concurrent users)

The above numbers are to give an indication of scale. I may wind up with more integers in the set (new characteristics added) or with more Target sets (more profiles) or with more concurrent requests (more concurrent users), but this is good for now

If it helps, I am happy with results being clustered in buckets. I.e. top 10,000 results in a top 1% bucket. Next 10,000 results in a top 2% bucket, etc. I do not necessarily care about order within each such bucket (too granular a distinction for the end user to warrant any added performance investment).

Equally, because an end user would never fit 1,000,000 results in their UI, I am happy if the algorithm somehow only returns a smaller subset of returns (for example - only the top matches). But further browsing should still load the rest of the list in a performant way.

A practical use case; imagine a dating app where an end user is asked to rate, on a slider bar, 50 characteristics for how important they are to them. And where the app returns the best matches, updated 'live' as you makes edits.

Which techniques / type of algorithms are best suited to tackle this requirement?

Initial attempts use Squared Euclidean Distance, but this proves too resource intensive given the size of data and the performance requirements. 
Bigger differences for a given characteristic ideally do carry more weight (as they do when using the Squared Euclidean Distance method)

Comment: Use an **index** to speed up similarity search. Fairly standard problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need that performance, you're going to need to abandon a complete characteristic-to-characteristic comparison I think. 2 possibilities:

1) Do a sum-of-all-characteristics comparison first (or only). This can be fast because it can be pre-computed/pre-indexed of course on your target set. By my estimate, you'll get about 200-400 targets with the identical sum of an average source. (And about 200-400 targets with sum one greater, 200-400 targets with sum one less, etc.). You can then (optionally) look within these smaller "tranches" for closer/farther matches on the characteristics individually.

2) In typical problems of this type, "not all characteristics are equal". Consider, if you can, identifying a number <<50 of "key" characteristics, either global or varying per-query/user (or some of both). Again the target set can be pre-indexed on those (or on their sum) for speed.

More advice than a solution, but fwiw...

Comment: Appreciated regardless! :) Sum-of-all-characteristics, you mean a sum of the absolute difference for each characteristics, yes? The 'key' characteristics are those that have big differences (for example - anything with a difference over 40). This does mean the key characteristics are likely to still be different for each pairing. Adding in case it raises an opportunity.

Comment: No, I mean straight sum of the values of the 50 characteristics, for each individual target and each individual source, then only comparing the source sum to target sums. As a first approximation. Because it can be pre-computed for targets.

Answer (score 0):

Using manhattan distance (instead of squared euclidean distance) and 500,000 sets (instead of 1mil) I'm getting a timing of ~700ms in IE11 (client side). Server side I can't see any reason why you couldn't get sub second processing time.

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/66mwupqn/

```
function makeSets(size) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i<size; i++) {
        var row = []
        for(var j=0; j<50; j++) {
            row[j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        }
        result[i] = row;
    }
    return result;
}
function sortSets(value, collection) {
    for(var i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
        var score = 0;
        for(var j=0; j<50; j++) {
            score += Math.abs(collection[i][j] - value[j]);
        }
        collection[i].score = score;
    }
    return collection.sort(function(a,b){return b.score-a.score;});
}

var list = makeSets(500000);
var value = makeSets(1)[0];
var t = Date.now();
var result = sortSets(value, list);
t = Date.now() - t;
alert("Time (ms) : " + t + ", Result (scores) : " + result[0].score + " - " + result[result.length-1].score);
```

I'm using the *Array.prototype.sort* which has terrible performance. Using an in-place quick sort I could probably get sub second time with client side JavaScript.

**EDIT** 1100ms to score and sort 1mil sets of 50 values (1-100) each, calculating a manhattan distance score for each set vs a value, JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5gc37jmb/ with an in-place quick sort implementation, on an i5 5200U processor (not a power chip).

**If JavaScript on a low power laptop can do it, I can't see why a server would have any trouble**